# How to force an event?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am having a problem with some control i downloaded, i want to change the background when the button is pressed, but it seems that when the button is pressed the app will not listen to any event until the current event is finished here is my code

```
-(void) menuItem:(RRCircularItem *)item didChangeActive:(BOOL)active {

    [menu progress];
    [menu setBackgroundColor1:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuabiertoloadingretina.png"]]];
    [menu hideWithAnimationBlock:^{
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }];
    [menu release], menu = nil;
     self.viewCarga.hidden = NO;
    [menu setBackgroundColor1:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuabiertoloadingretina.png"]]];
    NSLog(@"Item %@ did change state to %d", item.text, active);
    if ([item.text isEqualToString:@"EDITORIALES"]){

        ViewController *viewControler = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"EditorialesViewController" bundle:nil];
        [self presentViewController:viewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
        [menu setBackgroundColor1:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menuabiertoloadingretina.png"]]];

    }else if ([item.text isEqualToString:@"GOLES"]){

        GolViewController *viewControler = [[GolViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"GolViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else if ([item.text isEqualToString:@"TABLA"]){

        WebViewController *viewControler = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else if ([item.text isEqualToString:@"AUNLI"]){

        AUNLIViewController *viewControler = [[AUNLIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AUNLIViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else if ([item.text isEqualToString:@"HORARIOS"]){

        HorariosViewController *viewControler = [[HorariosViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HorariosViewController" bundle:nil];

        [self presentViewController:viewControler animated:YES completion:nil];
    }

    if (active && ![menu isLabelActive]) {
        [menu setLabelActive:YES];
        [menu setSliderValue:1];
    } else if (!active && [menu isLabelActive]) {
        BOOL hasActive = NO;
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) hasActive |= [menu isItemActive:i];
        if (!hasActive) {
            [menu setLabelActive:NO];
            [menu setSliderValue:0 animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

i want to use this event `[menu progress];` before everything, but it is not working.

Comment: You are asking about UI components we don't know. Also, it's obvious you have problems grasping other obj-c concepts, like the ownership of objects in MRC. Your issues is probably caused by the misunderstanding of iOS events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understand Well, you press some button and you stay lock.Its because you are doing everything in main thread. Thats why you need to use threads, this way you will do multi sync/async processes preventing locks in your app. You can use NSThread, dispatch or NSOperationQueue...I like to use 
[GCD(Grand Central Dispatch)](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)

Sample:

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
    //Background Thread
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //User Interface Updates
    });
});
```